# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver

Tags: hadoop, hive

i am setting hadoop and hive in 2 computer .
in machine 1: everything ok.
in machine 2: when i start hive, it have error with message:

```
15/07/17 09:37:54 INFO util.ApplicationClassLoader: system classes: [java., javax.accessibility., javax.activation., javax.activity., javax.annotation., javax.annotation.processing., javax.crypto., javax.imageio., javax.jws., javax.lang.model., -javax.management.j2ee., javax.management., javax.naming., javax.net., javax.print., javax.rmi., javax.script., -javax.security.auth.message., javax.security.auth., javax.security.cert., javax.security.sasl., javax.sound., javax.sql., javax.swing., javax.tools., javax.transaction., -javax.xml.registry., -javax.xml.rpc., javax.xml., org.w3c.dom., org.xml.sax., org.apache.commons.logging., org.apache.log4j., org.apache.hadoop., core-default.xml, hdfs-default.xml, mapred-default.xml, yarn-default.xml]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ApplicationClassLoader.loadClass(ApplicationClassLoader.java:170)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:278)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:214)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

i tried to fix. but i couldn't.

in hive/lib. i found to lib hive-cli-1.2.1.jar. i used hadoop 2.6.0 and hive 1.2.1

Comment: Are there any jars present locally in the location where you executed hive. Try changing the location to a different directory and try hive again.

Comment: i tried to change location, setting in another user but i still get same error

Comment: Do u have any previous versions of hadoop installed on that machine. Can you check hadoop version. Try checking the value of HADOOP_HOME also

Comment: i installed them(hadoop 2.6.0 & hive 1.2.1) before. but i removed them (and removed user ) and install in another user. my hadoop version 2.6.0